# Adding a class to a div when the div is on scrolled into the screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to add the fadeInTop class to the div with the class animation. The Javascript is not working correctly...

The console returns me this which goes back to that line:
document.querySelectorAll(".animated".classList.add(fadeInTop))

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
    at application.js:41:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at IntersectionObserver.<anonymous> (application.js:39:1)
```

This is in the application.js file:

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"


const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if(entry.isIntersecting){
      document.querySelectorAll(".animated".classList.add(fadeInTop))
    }
  })
})

observer.observe(document.querySelector(".containerFadeIn"))
```

This is from the home.html.erb view:

```
<main class="home-main">
<%# fist box %>

  <div class="home-text-1 containerFadeIn">
    <div class="row containerFadeIn">
      <div class="col-md-9 d-flex animated">
        <div class="vendo-logo-home">
          <%= image_tag "vendo-logo.png"%>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>The Future begins</h1>
          <h1 > with <span class="light-blue"><strong>VENDO</strong></span></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

my main goal is to make the text fade into the screen when the text is scrolled into the screen (if i add the fadeInTop class to the  the fade in animation works)

Comment: Take a look at the placement of parentheses here: `document.querySelectorAll(".animated".classList.add(fadeInTop))` and check what is returned by document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look right `document.querySelectorAll(".animated".classList.add(fadeInTop))`

- If you are calling `document.querySelectorAll` this should return node list  so you need to iterate through all elements like:

`document.querySelectorAll(".animated").forEach(element => element.classList.add("fadeInTop"))`

Keep in mind that nodelist is not an array but it does accept forEach method. You might want to convert that into array like `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".animated"))` and then call forEach method.

- If you have only one element then you can call:

`document.querySelector(".animated").classList.add("fadeInTop")`

Comment: This worked for me document.querySelectorAll(".animated").forEach(element => element.classList.add("fadeInTop")) Thank you so much